# MagicaVoxel Render workspace showing only flat white & grey gradient?

Tags: workspace, magicavoxel

Is this behavior expected?  Why is it doing this?  And how do I fix it?

This is all I see whenever I click the Render workspace:
[image: This is all I see whenever I click the Render workspace]

Apparently it's only the "water" material (teal blue) at the bottom of my 126 x 126 x 126 that isn't showing up in my render workspace.  I've included several screenshots below to illustrate the problem.

How it looks in the Model workspace:
[image: How it looks in the Model workspace]

Notice how the water doesn't "show up" in the Render Workspace beneath the brown object:
[image: Notice how the water doesn't "show up" in the Render Workspace beneath the brown object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to fix:

Step 1 - While still in the "Model" workspace/view, click the double-arrows (facing horizontally) at the top right of the window (just to the left of the word "Edit").
[image: Step 1]

Step 2 - Hold click & drag the blue arrow facing skyward until your model is ABOVE the render plane (anything below position 0 on the graph will be cut off in Render view).
[image: Step 2]

Example:
[image: Step 3]

Finished Result:
[image: Step 4]

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent example in answering your own query properly and thoroughly, recognising as you clearly do that this will help others facing the same confusion with Magica Voxel - nicely done - and welcome to **GDSE**, by the way! You might want to look at [tour] for an overview - but looks like you're already getting the hang of both Magica Voxel *and* **GDSE**!